# How can I add JsonDerivedType without attributes in runtime in System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

Here is my code:

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using static WinFormsApp1.Form1;

namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var i=JsonSerializer.Serialize<BaseClass>(new TestClass<int>() { Name = "123", Value = "456", Tag = 1 });
            var j = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<BaseClass>(i);
        }

        [JsonDerivedType(typeof(BaseClass), typeDiscriminator: "1")]
        [JsonDerivedType(typeof(TestClass<int>), typeDiscriminator: "2")]
        public class BaseClass
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }

        public class TestClass<T> : BaseClass { 
            public T Tag { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to serialize different class which are based on `BaseClass`. And I want to be able to deserialize correctly again in the future.

By using the `JsonDerivedType`, I can solve what I need easily.

However, now I have a problem. The `BaseClass` is in a third-party library and I cannot add attribute below to it because the third-party is compiled.

```
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(TestClass<int>), typeDiscriminator: "2")]
```

If I don't add this attribute, it will throw error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Runtime type 'WinFormsApp1.Form1+TestClass`1[System.Int32]' is not supported by polymorphic type 'WinFormsApp1.Form1+BaseClass'. Path: $.'

So, I have to find a way to add `JsonDerivedType` without attribute. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What would you do if the base class is changed significantly in some future update to the third party library? This sounds quite risky to me. I would consider creating some Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) for serialization, so you have full control over the type hierarchy whenever you want to deserialize.

Comment: @JonasH The third-party company clearly told me that this library may change in the future, but this model(the base class) will never.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beginning with [.NET 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-7#systemtextjson-serialization), You can use a custom [`JsonTypeInfo` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts#modifiers) to add [`JsonDerivedType` metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-8-0) to System.Text.Json's contract metadata in runtime.

First, define the following modifier:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> AddPolymorphismOptions(Type baseType, JsonPolymorphismOptions options) => (typeInfo) =>
    {
        if (baseType.IsSealed)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Cannot add JsonPolymorphismOptions to sealed base type {baseType.FullName}");
        if (typeInfo.Type.IsAssignableTo(baseType) && !typeInfo.Type.IsSealed)
        {
            typeInfo.PolymorphismOptions = new()
            {
                IgnoreUnrecognizedTypeDiscriminators = options.IgnoreUnrecognizedTypeDiscriminators,
                TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = options.TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName,
                UnknownDerivedTypeHandling = options.UnknownDerivedTypeHandling,
            };
            foreach (var derivedType in options.DerivedTypes.Where(t => !t.DerivedType.IsAbstract && t.DerivedType.IsAssignableTo(typeInfo.Type)))
                typeInfo.PolymorphismOptions.DerivedTypes.Add(derivedType);         
        }
    };
}
```

Then construct your `JsonSerializerOptions` e.g. as follows, using either a [`DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.defaultjsontypeinforesolver) instance or some [`JsonSerializerContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonserializercontext) instance if you are using [source generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/source-generation):

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    // Configure either a DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver or some JsonSerializerContext and add the required modifier:
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver() 
        .WithAddedModifier(JsonExtensions.AddPolymorphismOptions(
            typeof(BaseClass), 
            new ()
            {
                DerivedTypes = { new(typeof(BaseClass), "1"), 
                                new(typeof(TestClass<int>), "2"), },
            }
        )),
    // Set other options as required.
};
```

Then serialize your model as follows:

```
var i = JsonSerializer.Serialize<BaseClass>(new TestClass<int>() { Name = "123", Value = "456", Tag = 1 }, options);
var j = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<BaseClass>(i, options);
```

And everything will round-trip successfully.

Notes:

- [`WithAddedModifier()`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-8/#ijsontypeinforesolver-withaddedmodifier) was added in .NET 8.  In .NET 7 you must configure a `DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver` directly:

  ```
  var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
  {
      TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver() 
      {
          Modifiers = 
          {
              JsonExtensions.AddPolymorphismOptions(
                  typeof(BaseClass), 
                  new ()
                  {
                      DerivedTypes = { new(typeof(BaseClass), "1"), 
                                      new(typeof(TestClass<int>), "2"), },
                  }
              )                   
          },
      },
      // Set other options as required.
  };
  ```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hNABde).